# Nesting related elements together parent/child

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have an array as so with objects:

```
[
  {
    "id": "5a97e047f826a0111b754beb",
    "name": "Hogwarts",
    "parentId": "5c7bf2191d41c810b2ad6186",
    "childrenIds": []
  },
  {
    "id": "5c7bf2191d41c810b2ad6186",
    "name": "Defense Against The Dark Arts",
    "parentId": null,
    "childrenIds": [
      "5a97e047f826a0111b754beb"
    ]
  }
]
```

What I'd like to do is a function that returns another array, but this time with only items that don't have a parentID as root elements, and have a children array on them containing their children, so on reaching leaves who have an empty childrenIDs array. (also remove the parent/children id properties)

For the previous input I'd return something like this

```
[
  {
    "id": "5c7bf2191d41c810b2ad6186",
    "name": "Defense Against The Dark Arts",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "5a97e047f826a0111b754beb",
        "name": "Hogwarts"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I can't seem to think of any efficient code for this task, can anyone help?

Comment: Can you think of any *inefficient* code for this task?

Comment: Loop over to find all parents (null parentid), add them to a new array and remove them from the old, loop over original array again and assign them as children to their parents if their parents are on the new array, loop over again through incrementing a counter to tell what level you're on until the original array is empty. (delete undesired keys while at it)

Comment: That's the only approach that came to mind but I doubt it's the best out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep a reference to each node by ID in an object and build the tree while you go. Since we may encounter references to entries that we didn't see yet, we'll create stubs in the meantime (consisting only of a children array) and add the rest of their fields later on.

This way we have only a single loop.

It seems you have sort of a vertical double-linked list, saving both the parent ID in the children and the children's IDs in the parent, but we need only one of those to build the tree. We'll use the parent ID stored in each child. (Note that this assumes that your structure is consistent without imbalanced relations or dangling references.)

For simplicity, we create one root node whose children we'll return at the end, so that we don't have to handle the nodes without parent any differently.

Then you could write code like this:

```js
function makeTree (rows) {
  // Use a symbol to denote the root ID to avoid clashes with any real IDs
  const ROOT = Symbol('ROOT')

  // Node index, by ID
  // Add a root node from the start
  const nodes = { [ROOT]: { children: [] } }

  // Helper function to return an existing node or create a stub if not existing
  const getNodeOrCreateStub = id => nodes[id] || (nodes[id] = { children: [] })

  for (const row of rows) {
    // Add current row to index, merging data with existing stub, if any.
    // This keeps any existing references in other nodes' children arrays intact
    // because Object.assign mutates the first object passed to it and returns the
    // same object.
    const node = Object.assign(getNodeOrCreateStub(row.id), row)

    // Remove unwanted properties.
    delete node.parentId
    delete node.childrenIds

    // Get parent or create parent stub if parent node not already existing
    const parent = getNodeOrCreateStub(row.parentId || ROOT)

    // Add current node as child to parent
    parent.children.push(node)
  }

  // Return children of root node
  return nodes[ROOT].children
}
```

Note that this code currently also creates empty `children` arrays in the leaf nodes, differently from your example above. However I think this makes the code simpler because it doesn't have to handle leaf nodes any different, neither in creating the tree nor in reading it later! (You wouldn't have to do `children && children.length` to check for children, you could always just access `children` directly.)

To change that and have the result exactly as in your example, you'd change the code as follows:

```js
// Change this...
const getNodeOrCreateStub = id => nodes[id] || (nodes[id] = { children: [] })
// ...to this:
const getNodeOrCreateStub = id => nodes[id] || (nodes[id] = {})

// Also change this...
parent.children.push(node)
// ...to this:
if (!parent.children) parent.children = []
parent.children.push(node)
// ...or to this:
parent.children = [...parent.children || [], node]
```

Comment: This answer is absolutely perfect and very well explained and more than I could ask for, thank you very much I've learned alot from it. <3

Comment: Happy I could help. Note that I fine-tuned it a few minutes ago, so maybe read over it again just to be sure you got the latest version ;)